# Lord of the Ring LCG: Gandalf and Expert Treasure-hunter

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings-lcg

When using "Gandalf" as a hero, one plays with the top card of the deck faceup. If I attach "Expert Treasure-hunter" to one of my heroes, does it mean that I automatically get a card in my hand after this hero quests successfully (since I am able to see the type of the card)?

If I attach one copy of "Expert Treasure-hunter" to each of my heroes, do I first turn the top card of my deck faceup before each guessing or do I have to guess 3 cards at the same times, seeing only the first one?

**Gandalf** (Hero)

> Play with the top card of your deck faceup. Once per phase, you may play the top card of your deck as if it was in your hand. [...]

**Expert Treasure-hunter** (Attachment)

> Attach to a hero. Limit 1 per hero.
>   **Response**: After attached hero quests successfully, name a card type and discard the top card of your deck. If the discarded card is the named type, take it into your hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; Your assumptions are correct - you can 'automatically' draw three cards on a successful quest with three Expert Treasure-hunter attached to your heroes and a Gandalf (hero).

---

To answer your first question, yes. If have Gandalf (Hero) and Expert Treasure-hunter attached to a hero when you quest successfully on Expert Treasure-hunter's triggered ability activation you can name the type of the card on the top of you deck, then discard and draw it.

For the second question I think the key is Gandalf's `Play with the top card of your deck faceup.` This means that the top card of your deck (provided your deck has cards in it) is ALWAYS revealed as long as you have Gandalf's ability. Thus during each activation of the three Expert Treasure-hunters the top card of your library will be revealed and you can name its type, then discard and draw it. Id est you can *automatically* draw three cards on each successful quest with Gandalf and three Expert Treasure-Hunter's attached to your three heroes.

The source for my interpretation is the "The Lord of the Rings: The Card Game Online Rules Reference" found on the Fantasy Flight Games [website](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/products/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-card-game/). In particular the second Golden Rule (page 2):

> If the ability text of a card directly contradicts the text of either the Rules Reference Guide or the Learn to Play book, the text of the card takes precedence.

implying that the top card of your deck is ALWAYS revealed if you have the Gandalf hero's ability. And the definitions of Response (page 14):

> Response:
>   Response abilities are labeled by the word “Response” followed by ability text. Unlike action abilities, which are resolved during action windows, response abilities may be executed after the specified triggering condition occurs, as described in the response’s ability text. 
>    - It is possible for multiple responses to be executed from the same triggering condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your research. I agree with your interpretation of the rules you quoted.